# How to wait service response in foreach (map)?

Tags: angular

```
  this.orderTrackings.map((v:any)=>{
            let request = {
                "description": "",
                "destinationFromCode": v.destinationfromCode,
                "destinationToCode": v.destinationtoCode,
                "ordItemNum": v.orditemnum,
                "ordnum": this.ordnum
            };
            this.restService.post( '/uomback/sordtracking/handlerequest', request).subscribe((r:any) => {
                this.getOrderTrackingInfo(v.orditemnum,true);
            });
```

I need to wait until handlerequest get response to call for next item. Any suggestion?

Comment: you can use `forkJoin`

Comment: how to use that in my case?

Comment: i dont know how many items i will have and in my case i need to call api for next request when i get response from previous

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use an `exhaustMap` to have the http request finish before moving on to the next request.

Example:

```js
Observable.of(...this.orderTrackings)
    .map((v:any) => ({
        description: "",
        destinationFromCode: v.destinationfromCode,
        destinationToCode: v.destinationtoCode,
        ordItemNum: v.orditemnum,
        ordnum: this.ordnum,
    }).exhaustMap((request) => {
        return this.restService.post('/uomback/sordtracking/handlerequest', request)
                               .map((response: Response) => ({response, request});
    }).subscribe((r:any) => {
        this.getOrderTrackingInfo(r.request.ordItemNum, true);
    });
```

With this setup `getOrderTrackingInfo` will be called once after every `POST`.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you shouldn't wait for this execution. Just put everything you want to do afterwards to subscribe. Asynchronous operations are asynchronous because they should be.